# Class(Child window )destructor not getting called

Tags: c++, winapi

I have created a window which has a toolbar with some icons, and I launch one more window clicking on the available icon from the main window.

First window is created using CreateWindowEx method.
the one I click using an icon is created using dialog resource.
So without closing dialog, I directly close the main window. I see that dialog window is not getting closed.
When I debug, control does not come to destructor of second window.

When I close them individually (i.e dialog first) and then main window next,then everything is fine.

Please help,that what might be missing when I close the main window.

I mean class desctructor is not getting called.

Comment: Um, windows don't have destructors; what exactly do you mean?

Comment: You are clearly using a C++ framework that wraps the windows API. There are a number of ways frameworks could get confused here, ATL, WTL and MFC *should* be quite reliable. Others can get confused with out-of-order destruction. Which one do you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

Handle your main window's message `WM_CLOSE` and check, whether the dialog window is open or not. If dialog window is open, just close it using the handle you got returned while loading it from resources.